# SharePoint ULS logs HTTP 304 Not Modified responses with errors - by design?

Tags: http, cache, sharepoint

We've noticed a correlation between HTTP 304 responses to requests for SharePoint *Style Library* assets and ULS error-like messages in the same correlation such as:

Event ID **ab1a9**

> Failed to get document content data. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete this function     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)

Event ID **abq2i**

> Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80004005.

Event ID **aiv4w**

> Spent 0 ms to bind -1 byte file stream

Event ID **aise3**

> Failure when fetching document. 0x80070012

Does anyone know if it's by design? Is this correlation real or accidental?

Comment: This question may or may not be migrated to sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you add context to what you are seeing with the 304?  What is it trying to access in there, and what is it returning after the 304?  It's very possible, especially if you have upgraded from a previous version where Microsoft has internal controls to replace referenced objects.

Comment: It's a clean install of SharePoint 2013. We see these "errors" when the browser requests cached resources from Style Library (images, stylesheets, scripts) and the server responds with 304 Not Modified.